Even the app is closed or in terminated show full screen payment notification

Like a popular payment app, after payment completed. Send a full screen notification if the app is in terminated state, without any user any user interactions the notification shown in full screen.
So even if the app is closed or in terminated state or idle and without any user any user interactions, full screen notification should appear on the device.
(In my perspective it will look like kind of ads.)
The notification should not appear inside the notification bar.
How to achieve it?
